# Как мне сложить числа в клетках QTableWidget при их перемещении друг на друга с помощью drag`n`drop

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

У меня есть таблица QTableWidget, нужно при переносе одной ячейки на другую сложить числа, записанные в ячейках

[image: начальная таблица с числами][image: как должно получиться]

Пытался переопределить метод dropEvent, но при попытке сложить клетки вылетает ошибка

```
void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event){
        QTableWidgetItem *target = itemAt(event->position().toPoint());
        int number = target->text().toInt();

        QTableWidget::dropEvent(event);

        QTableWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->position().toPoint());
        target->setText(QString::number(number+item->text().toInt()));
}
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Здесь не приветствуется текст ошибки в виде картинки, это затрудняет поиск.

Comment: Зачем здесь-то рекурсия?

Comment: Ну так выполнение функции drop, чтобы потом посмотреть, как поменялся элемент

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что я обращался не к тому объекту

```
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event){
            QTableWidgetItem *target = itemAt(event->position().toPoint());
            int number = target->text().toInt();

            QTableWidget::dropEvent(event);

            QTableWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->position().toPoint());
            item->setText(QString::number(number+item->text().toInt()));
    }
```